# Use of undeclared type Date

Tags: ios, swift2, nsdate, xcode7.3

Which framework need to import to solve the below compile time error in swift :-

> Use of undeclared type "Date'

[image]

Comment: In which version of Xcode and Swift you are getting this ?

Comment: Xcode 7.3 and swift 2.2

Comment: @pkc456  - then use bhavin answer.,

Comment: @pkc456: As I suspected the issue is with the version. The above code will work in Swift 3.0, it won't work in Swift 2.2 because those classes are introduced in Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8

Comment: importing  Foundation framework solves this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift 3.0 apple removed the NS prefix ,if you are used Xcode8 with beta 4 and above you can use this

```
func hours(fromdate: Date) -> Int {
        // Your code
    }
```

If you are used in below Swift3 then we need to use NSxxx instead  of all

```
func hours(fromdate: NSDate) -> Int {
        // Your code
    }
```

Comment: NS --> removed in only Swift3 not in swift below verson of Swift , so you can use NSDate in this place of Date

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned Swift 2.0 in your tags. So simply use this :

First import this framework in your class:

```
import Foundation
```

Than :

```
func hours(fromdate: NSDate) -> Int {
     // your code
}
```

Important note :

- As i am also currently working with swift 2.0 so the above method is tried & tested of my code.

Hope it will guide you.

Answer (score 2):

The Date class is introduced in Swift 3.0 & Xcode 8. So you won't get it in Swift 2.2 version. You need to use `NSDate` instead.

In Swift 3.0 apple removed the `NS` prefix from the classes.

1. `NSDate` became `Date`
2. `NSCalendar` became `Calendar`

Comment: Good to know. Thanks Midhun